# wget and <video> tag

Tags: html, wget, html5

I'm using wget to recursively download all pages from the website(includin all css, js and images)

that works great except it does not follow `<video>` tag and do not download video files

is there some solution for it ?

Answer (score 1):

It should be working now. 
It seems wget has a bug preventing to download the  of the  tag. See https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-wget/2013-06/msg00070.html

Using the ‐‐page-requisites option might also help.

I gleaned this info from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29693346/why-wget-does-not-download-included-videos